# Creating an update trigger to update a column in table1 based on a value in table2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

**UPDATE AT BOTTOM OF THIS POST**

---

I have two tables in SQL Server, a simplified view of each is below.

**Table1**

```
| ObjectID | Name | Email |
+----------+------+-------+
| 1        | Ben  |       |
| 2        | Tom  |       |
```

**Table2**

```
| ObjectID  | Name |     Email     |
+-----------+------+---------------+
| 52        | Ben  | ben@email.com |
| 53        | Tom  | tom@email.com |
```

I want to create a trigger in the database which updates table1, whereby when I update the name field the trigger fires, and inserts the email address which can be found in table2.

Note: both tables have many more columns

Note2: when a row is inserted into table 1, it ONLY receives an ObjectID, then an update is done where the user adds the Name.

After the user adds this name is where I want the database to run off and look at table2, find a matching name, and return to table1 and write the data within.

I have written (unsuccessfully) the below code, I have tried using `update()` and a heap of other things, but I feel I am way off the mark:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "acc_insert_email" 
ON TABLE1
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TABLE1(email)
        SELECT i.email 
        FROM TABLE1 t 
        INNER JOIN TABLE2 i ON t.email = i.email
END
```

Can anyone point me back in the correct direction?

Thanks in advance.

---

So I have tested the answer provided by @Ezlo but have not had any luck... I slightly modified it to instead insert the word TEST in the column, to see if it will even do that, but this also has no effect. This is the code I have currently, note I have used actual table and column names:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "gisadmin"."acc_UpdateOfficerDetails" ON NOXIOUS_WEED_INSPECTION_POINT AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    IF UPDATE(authorised_officer_email)
    BEGIN

        UPDATE T SET
            authorised_officer_email = 'TEST'
        FROM
            inserted AS I
            INNER JOIN NOXIOUS_WEED_INSPECTION_POINT AS T ON I.authorised_officer = T.authorised_officer
            LEFT JOIN AUTH_DB.authlive.dbo.acc_weave_emp_details AS N ON I.authorised_officer = N.cus_idd

    END
END
```

`authorised_officer` and `cus_idd` is the staff username (I have successfully done a simple join on these two fields, it works fine, so I have ruled out two different data types being the issue)

So I am perplexed as to why this trigger is not even inserting simple 'TEST' text for me.

Any ideas?

---

Below is the final code which answers my original question, works fantastic! Thanks @EzLo

```
CREATE TRIGGER "gisadmin"."acc_UpdateOfficerDetails" ON NOXIOUS_WEED_INSPECTION_POINT AFTER
UPDATE AS BEGIN IF
UPDATE
    (authorised_officer) BEGIN
UPDATE
    T
SET
    authorised_officer_email = A.mto_lst
FROM
    inserted AS I
INNER JOIN
    NOXIOUS_WEED_INSPECTION_POINT AS T
ON
    I.authorised_officer = T.authorised_officer
LEFT JOIN
    AUTH_DB.authlive.dbo.acc_weave_emp_details AS A
ON
    I.authorised_officer = A.cus_idd
END
END
```

Comment: Why you want to create trigger. Create a stored procedure which accepts name as a parameter. Based on the name, get the corresponding email address from table2 and insert into table1. Triggers should generally be avoided, unless in rare scenarios. triggers make the transaction lengthier and difficult to debug and troubleshoot issues.

Comment: @VenkataramanR thanks very much for this suggestion, I am new to back end database things, I will research stored procedure to see if this will suffice :)

Comment: @VenkataramanR can a stored procedure run on an update to the table rows? Or are stored procedures triggered manually?

Comment: Storeprocedure not run on the update but will use it to insert in both tables.

Comment: but, your requirement also be done using trigger. just need to calify the working flow.

Comment: @Benno, Stored procedures are generally manually triggered. You can also call stored procedure inside trigger. I was suggesting that instead of trigger, you can have a stored procedure, which does INSERT into table1  with Name, EmailAddress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_UpdateTable1Email ON TABLE1 AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    IF UPDATE(Name)
    BEGIN

        UPDATE T SET
            Email = N.Email
        FROM
            inserted AS I
            INNER JOIN TABLE1 AS T ON I.Name = T.Name
            LEFT JOIN TABLE2 AS N ON I.Name = N.Name

    END
END
```

Trigger will execute on `TABLE1` updates and the inner update will only be done if the original update statement includes the `name` column. `inserted` is a special trigger table that holds the rows of the tracking table (`TABLE1` in this case) that were updated. Join `inserted` with `TABLE1` to be able to update the correct emails, then go search the emails to update to `TABLE2`.

Let me mention that you have denormalized data, and this causes maintainance issues (what happens if someone updates name or email from `TABLE2`? records at `TABLE1` will be out of sync). You should keep the names and emails (and other related data) in just 1 place, so only one update is needed.

---

**EDIT**: Update on more than 1 column (no parenthesis needed).

```
ALTER TRIGGER "gisadmin"."acc_UpdateOfficerDetails" ON NOXIOUS_WEED_INSPECTION_POINT AFTER UPDATE 
AS 
BEGIN 
    IF UPDATE (authorised_officer) 
    BEGIN

        UPDATE
            T
        SET
            authorised_officer_email = A.mto_lst,
            authorised_officer_phone = A.bus_mob
        FROM
            inserted AS I
        INNER JOIN
            NOXIOUS_WEED_INSPECTION_POINT AS T
        ON
            I.authorised_officer = T.authorised_officer
        LEFT JOIN
            AUTH_DB.authlive.dbo.acc_weave_emp_details AS A
        ON
            I.authorised_officer = A.cus_idd

    END
END
```

Comment: This looks very promising @EzLo, and I am able to understand what it is doing due to your explanation, thanks very much. I have now converted from my basic example to match my real world database, the trigger is valid and is not throwing errors when I create it. I have just tested it by updating a few rows of staff names, but I am not seeing any data in the column I would expect to see the data in, basically I am not sure the trigger is firing. Is there any way I can test this do you know? In python I would insert print statements, but SQL is not that simple. Thanks

Comment: @Benno you can switch the `UPDATE T SET` part for a `SELECT` so if it executes then you should see a result set from the trigger. Make sure you are updating the column `Name` from `TABLE1` in you update or else the trigger logic won't apply. You should also see a message similar to "(X row(s) affected)" from the update inside the trigger (so you would have 2 messages, one for your update of the name and another from the trigger, if you didn't `SET NOCOUNT ON`). **Edit**: seems that your IF is on the wrong column, it should be `authorised_officer` and it's now `authorised_officer_email`.

Comment: you hit the nail on the head, spot on! Thanks. I have just put the final working code in my original post. One last minor question, can I update two fields using one trigger? Or do I have to separate them into two? I wanted to add modify this `SET authorised_officer_email = A.mto_lst` too instead be `SET (authorised_officer_email = A.mto_lst, authorised_officer_phone = A.bus_mob)`, but when I try this I get the below error: `{0:0} Incorrect syntax near '('.`, is there a way to do this correctly?

Comment: @Benno don't need the parenthesis on updates, just separate each column with a comma and done. I edited my answer with your example.